# Validating a text box of a User Form

Tags: excel, vba, textbox, userform

I have two sheets named "In-house inventory" and "Maintenance Details". I am using a User Form to feed data into the Maintenance Details datasheet. There is a combo box to select the material type used for the maintenance and a text box to enter the quantity of the material used. I want to generate an error message if the material quantity entered by the user is greater than the available quantity of the material in the inventory. (For example, inventory has 15L of Lubricant oil, if the user selects Lubricant oil from the combo box and enter the quantity as 20L, I want to generate an error message saying that the Entered material quantity is greater than the available quantity in the inventory.)
This is what I did and this generates an error message for every value entered to the quantity text box.
I am very new to VBA and any help would be highly appreciated.
Thanks a lot in advance.

```
Private Sub MaterialQuantityTextBox_AfterUpdate()
    If MaterialQuantityTextBox.Value > Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Me.InhouseMaterialComboBox, Sheet6.Range("B:D"), 3, False) Then
        MsgBox " Quantity is greater than the quantity available in the Inventory. Enter a valid quantity"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: As the value in a textbox is probably regarded as text, try converting it to a number using one of the conversion methods.

Comment: Tried it, but still get the error message for every value